BufWritePost write stderr into a new buffer
I am writing an autocommand for compiling typst files when saving. It checks for the first line for locating the 'main' file, and this part works fine. I can also print the errors as messages in Neovim.
Howevere, I would like to display the error messages in a new buffer, and this fails since the functions for creating or writing to a buffer always raise an error.
The code is as follows, and I want to perform the commented operations in the on_stderr callback.
Yet, any of these lines raises the must not be called in a lua loop callback error.
local api = vim.api
local Job = require("plenary.job")

api.nvim_create_autocmd("BufWritePost", {
    pattern = { "*.typ" },
    callback = function()
        -- the actual code has more operations on file names
        -- but for a MWE it is essentially this line
        local current_file = api.nvim_buf_get_name(0)

        Job:new({
            command = "typst",
            args = { "c", current_file },
            on_stderr = function(_, data)
                if data then
                    -- local buffer = api.nvim_create_buf(true, false)
                    -- api.nvim_open_win(buffer, true, { split = 'below', win = 0 })
                    -- api.nvim_buf_set_lines(buffer, -1, -1, true, data)
                    vim.print(data)
                end
            end,
        }):start()
    end,
})

Please share you thoughts on how to print the stderr to a buffer in the BufWritePost callback. Any help is appreciated.
